# How to animate UIView in z-axis direction?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uicollectionview, core-animation

I am working on a collection view and wants to lift up UICollectionViewCell a little bit while user taps on it. I am changing the color of cells as well so it should stands out as compare to other cells while user taps on it.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

`view.layer.zPosition` does lift the view but it doesn't make it look nearer to the user (it doesn't get bigger) but only makes it go up in the layer hierarchy. If you desire to make it bigger you can also animate `view.transform` and put it to `CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.2, 1.2)` when selected/highlighted and back to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` when not selected/highlighted anymore.